# different subdomains but same apps in django

Tags: django, nginx, debian, subdomain, subdirectory

first some infos: In EVE-Online we have an Alliances and in there we have Corps.

My aim is to provide a domain as an Alliance. The subdomains should be named like the corps. Every corp can use the tools I installed in a subdirectorys but can also have their one installed as long as they don't have the folder of my apps.

Ex.

```
corp1.alli.com/map  -> to the maptool
corp2.alli.com/map  -> to the maptool
www.alli.com/map    -> to the maptool

corp1.alli.com/forum -> to the alli-forum
corp3.alli.com/forum -> to the alli-forum
www.alli.com/forum   -> to the alli-forum
```

but

```
corp1.alli.com/killboard -> to the killboard of corp1
corp2.alli.com/home      -> to the home of corp2
www.alli.com/home        -> not available
```

I have a VPS with nginx mysql and django running.

Oh, and the `sessionid` should be saved over all subdomains. I thing like `wildcard *.alli.com`

Is this possible and how could I realize that?

Comment: Are you looking for help with configuring nginx or setting up Django to respond to multiple subdomains?

Comment: I would say bought. I need to know how to set nginx for the different subdomains but same subfolder. Also what I have to in Django to accept the different subdomains.